# How to work around 3D Touch "Fast Switch" gobbling up touch events?

Tags: ios, iphone, 3dtouch

On iOS 9+, with iPhone 6s+ there is a feature called 3D Touch. It allows the phone to detect the pressure of a touch on the screen and applications can respond to that. The API mention Quick Actions and Peek & Pop as potential ways to work with it.

Not mentioned in the API documentation is a Fast Switch "gesture": hard press on the left side of the screen brings an app switcher. Optionally, you can also swipe right afterward.

The problem is that while the system is waiting to see if the user will press hard enough, it is not sending the touch (began) events to the app currently visible. This affects every single app that I have tested, including the very Settings/General/Accessibility/3DTouch screen where you can toggle 3DTouch on/off.

To replicate, simply enable 3DTouch and do a light press over the "< Accessibility" button in the top left. If you press over the 'y', the button lights up immediately. If you press over the "<" (quite close to the left side of the screen) it will take ~1s for the button to engage.

This was hard to describe, but now my question is: how to work around that!? I have a portrait-orientation game that relies on quick taps and they get lost if the user hits too close to the left side of the screen.

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do. Apple has been eroding the utility of multitouch since iOS 4.